# Is it ever appropriate to hyphenate a verb phrase in French which is used like a single word?

Tags: usage, grammaire, ponctuation

In French, there are many verb phrases which are used like single words, and are not to be interpreted along with the grammar of the surrounding sentence, eg. ‘mise à jour’, ‘mise en jeu’, ‘garde à vue’, ‘coup de gueule’, etc.  In English, one either tends to join these words together if they’re to be used like a noun, as German often does (eg. runaway, walkabout, notwithstanding, phonecall) or join them through hyphenation (eg. hold-up, hide-and-seek, down-to-earth).  Is it ever appropriate to do this in French, or are these verb phrases always used as plain separate words?

Comment: The rules for doing that in Dutch are quite well defined, and considering concatening up to 5 words is allowed, it's a good thing they are.

Comment: I've never seen `phonecall` written out as one word. Is that a thing I don't know about??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In French, we call *[mot composé](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mot_compos%C3%A9#Approche_grammaticale_pour_le_fran.C3.A7ais)* « un ensemble de mots formant une unité syntaxique et sémantique » (a series of words behaving as a single syntaxic and semantic unit). Whether the parts of a *mot composé* are linked by hyphens is almost entirely up to usage, and is determined by historical reasons. Examples of *mots composés* linked in various ways are:

- “cache-cache” et “saute-mouton” (hyphenated),
- “portemanteau” (agglutinated),
- “aujourd'hui” (apostrophe),
- “tête de nègre”, “petit pois” et “pommes de terre”.

But for each *mot composé*, the usage is rather well-established and does not vary depending on whether it is used. The only such example I can think of is: when a *mot composé* is [used as a colour, it may be hyphenated](http://francite.net/education/cyberprof/page235.html) (as noted by Joubarc, it is not [systematic](http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire11c.htm)):

> J'ai mangé une [tête de nègre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%AAte_de_n%C3%A8gre) après mes [petits pois](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petit_pois).
>   Je lui ai offert un pull tête-de-nègre et une jupe vert petit-pois.

<sup>(And it's not “une jupe vert**e** petit-pois”!)</sup>

Comment: Une jupe _vert petit-pois_ ou une _vert-petit-pois_ ?

Comment: @Joubarc Le premier : on garde séparés le nom de la couleur et ses qualificatifs (*un tapis vert pomme*).

Comment: Je trouvais que ce n'était pas très clair sur le lien que tu as donné, vu que les seuls exemples sont soit une juxtaposition de couleurs (_bleu-noir_), soit un mot composé (_lie-de-vin_). D'autre part, j'ai l'impression que pas mal de mots composés utilisés comme couleurs n'ont pas de trait d'union : [terre de Sienne](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/terre), [caca d'oie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/caca) — le trait d'union n'est [pas systématique](http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire11c.htm).

Comment: @Joubarc effectivement, c'est embêtant… j'ai corrigé ma réponse

Comment: En fait, _petit-pois_ n'est même pas une couleur officielle, si ?

Comment: @Joubarc hein ? Tu as une liste des couleurs officielles ?

Comment: Façon de parler :-) — je veux juste dire que je n'ai trouvé aucune référence à l'utilisation de _petit pois_ comme couleur ; et donc je cherchais à savoir si tu l'avais vu utilsé quelque part, ou si c'était une invention de ton cru.

Comment: BTW, at the risk of being frighteningly PC, I don't think "tête de nègre" is the favoured name for these cakes anymore... (it is definitely still *used*, but on its way out, I would say)

Comment: @Dave [wishful thinking](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=tête+de+nègre%2Ctête+de+choco%2Cwhippet&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3)

Comment: @F'x: being more of a word's usage in daily life (and its change over a span of 1-2 decades), I don't think ngrams are really the best indicator here. A look at any [recipe book](http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_tetes-de-choco-anciennement-tete-de-negre_31942.aspx) or down at your local Parisian bakery, should be enough to show a trend, though...

Comment: @Joubarc: Ça me rappelle [ce genre d'horreurs](http://formes-symboliques.org/article.php3?id_article=193).

Comment: @F'x: Whippet? Oh god. I had no idea :p I've never called them anything else than *têtes de nègres*. I didn't even know they had others names.

Answer (score 3):

*Mise à jour*, *mise en jeu*, *garde à vue*, *coup de gueule* can be analyzed and are used in the valid grammatical context (*mise*, *garde*, *coup* are names) even if they acquired a fixed meaning. They are called *locutions* and it is an intermediate state in the formation of words. Words further in the process may acquire hyphens or even be agglutinated.

Even early on, we are using hyphens either when the group of words isn't used in the grammatical context which would be demanded by the analysis (*fait-tout*, *saute-mouton*), when the meaning resulting of the analysis can still be employed (*après-demain*, *après demain*), when analysis is difficult or not possible (*cache-cache*, *porte-fenêtre*).

Agglutination is more common for older words (for which the compound formation is no more perceptible) and, obviously, when the components are though as prefix or suffix.